# SeleniumWebdriver - Driver finds element but cant work on it?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to make a simple test to test the login form of a website. When I initialize the element Selenium finds it but if I try to click on it or check if its Displayed I either get an exception that the element is not visible or False for the Displayed.

The page: http://www.officemate.co.th/

My code:

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.officemate.co.th");

    IWebElement openSignUp = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li.dropdown > a"));
    openSignUp.Click();

    IWebElement usernameField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserId"));

    usernameField.SendKeys("SomeUser");
    Console.WriteLine(usernameField.Displayed);
```

Comment: I think there is issue in css path. use x path and try. **html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a**

Comment: Your element locator is correct put wait function for userid field

Comment: @Darkbound check answer i have posted. And it is working code. hope so it'll help you if yes then accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

try following code. i have tested it is working fine.

```
try
        {
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Muhammad USman\Downloads\chromedriver_win32");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            //now i changed path for login.
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.officemate.co.th/Account/Login");


            //full specified xPath of eache element. is here whihc i'll use know.
            //https://www.officemate.co.th/Account/Login
            var email = @"/html/body/div[9]/div/fieldset/form/div[1]/div/input";
            var password = @"/html/body/div[9]/div/fieldset/form/div[2]/div/input";
            var check = @"/html/body/div[9]/div/fieldset/form/div[3]/div/input[1]";
            var login = @"/html/body/div[9]/div/fieldset/form/div[4]/div/button";


            IWebElement usernameField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(email));
            usernameField.Clear();
            usernameField.SendKeys("SomeUser@gmail.com");
            Console.WriteLine(usernameField.Displayed);

            IWebElement pass = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(password));
            pass.Clear();
            pass.SendKeys("Some!password");

            //Check box
            var checkBox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(check));
            if (!checkBox.Selected)
            {
                checkBox.Click();
            }

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(login)).Click();

            if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[9]/div/fieldset/form/div[1]/p")).Count > 0)
            {
                //invalid login error message
                var errorMessage = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[9]/div/fieldset/form/div[1]/p")).Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

if any issue then let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but I still get the same problem. First I get "Element is not interactable" exception on the usernameField.Clear() row, I deleted the row and then I get again the Element Not Visible exception... :(

Comment: Muhammad, could you help me?

Comment: I have retried code. and it is working fine. without any changes. i don't know why it is not working for you. you can try this (http://www.officemate.co.th/Account/Login) link for login may be it help you. but still if you facing issue then let me know. i can help you further on Skype.

Comment: @Darkbound know check i have updated answer. and changed the logic of login. know i think there is no confusion. and it is working fine  i have tested code above. if it complete your required options then accept question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is working, but, why the popup login is not?

Comment: Because in popup different tag with same attribute available. Also when we scroll down popup placed got changed. we need to get them again. As you said it is working then accept answer.